# Separating numbers in a string. Pascal

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I have a problem. I'm learning Pascal for only a couple of weeks and I don't know much. I have to write a program that has to calculate something out of 3 entered numbers. The problem is all 3 of them need to be entered in one edit with spaces in between. So basically I have a string 'number number number'. How do I separate these numbers as 3 separate strings so I can convert them into Integer.

Comment: `procedure GetNumbers(var  x,y,z: Integer); begin WriteLn('Enter three numbers separated with space and then press enter.'); ReadLn(x,y,z); end;`

Comment: @LURD I would be glad to UV your solution if you make it to a proper answer. The only current answer is not really an answer to the question and also overly complicated.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, thanks for encouraging me to go all the way to make an answer :-)

Comment: But the OP mentioned in "one edit" which to me presumes Lazarus IDE, readln doesn't work in that environment, no?

Comment: @juus, from the IDE, you could compile both console programs and GUI programs. Most questions with the pascal tag are school assignments requiring console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pascal there are built-in procedures to retrieve the input from the console.

The easiest way to get numeric inputs is to use `Read()/ReadLn()`, which also can make the conversion from string to a numeric value:

```
procedure GetNumbers(var x,y,z: Integer); 
begin 
  WriteLn('Enter three numbers separated with space and then press enter.');
  ReadLn(x,y,z); 
end;
```

Here, the `ReadLn()` detects three inputs separated with a space, waits for the <kbd>[Enter]</kbd> key and assigns the integer values to the x,y,z variables.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Does it works for arrays as well?

Comment: Yes: `Type TMyArr = array[0..2] of Integer; procedure GetNumbers(var arr: TMyArr); begin WriteLn('Enter three numbers separated with space and then press enter.'); ReadLn(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]); end;`

Comment: And if there's n elements? Like array[1..n] where n can be up to 100 000.

Comment: It's unlikely to manually enter 100 000 items in one edit line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the copy function is one way. Sorry about the formatting, I can't understand how to paste code snippets properly in these answer sections.

```
function TMyForm.Add( anEdit : TEdit ) : integer;
var
    Idx : integer;
    TempString : string;

function GetNext : integer;
begin
    result := result + StrToInt( copy( TempString, 1, Idx - 1 ) );
    TempString := copy( TempString, Idx + 1, MAXINT );
end;

begin
    result := 0;
    TempString := anEdit.Text;

    repeat
        Idx := pos( ' ', TempString );
        if Idx > 0 then
        result := GetNext;
    until Idx = 0;

    if trim( TempString ) <> '' then
        //this is the last piece of it then
        result := result + StrToInt( trim( TempString ) );
end;
```

You need to also take care that the values entered are numbers and not letters, usually done with try..except blocks.

Comment: The stackoverflow online help explains how to do proper formatting